# What does "If Machiavelli were a hacker, he'd have worked for the CSSG" mean

Tags: expressions, quotes

Machiavelli is a top guy in the "political science" field and Google shows CSSG as Computer Science Study Group. What does this quote mean?

> If Machiavelli were a hacker, he'd have worked for the CSSG.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that the author of this quote, Phil Lapsley, is a historian of "phone phreaking", hacking the telephone system, I would guess that the 'CSSG' in question is the Communications System Support Group, a public front behind which the NSA/CIA Special Collection Service hides certain covert electronic eavesdropping operations:

[image]
   —[LeakSource](http://leaksource.info/2013/06/14/there-is-an-nsacia-hybrid-agency-that-may-explain-snowdens-involvement-in-sigint-and-humint/)

Lapsley appears to be suggesting that the archetypal *Realpolitiker* Macchiavelli would have been right at home working for the amoral intelligence community.

Comment: It's funny that people use the phrase "if Michiavelli..." when discussing realpolitik since Michiavelli himself strongly disagrees with concepts we consider Michiavelliean today. He wrote The Prince as satire - taking the then conservative ideas to extremes to show how immoral those ideas can be. It's like if future historians would start to describe conservative ideas of the early 21st century as Colbertian.

Comment: @slebetman: There seems to be some debate on that subject; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prince#Interpretation_of_The_Prince_as_political_satire_or_as_deceit. Even those who agree that Machiavelli was pro-republic, despite the surface text of *The Prince*, do not all (or even mostly) think that *The Prince* was "satire" per se.

Answer (score 4):

The statement is most likely a commentary on the CSSG. This may be presumptuous, given we can't see the context, but I would read it as meaning roughly the same as "the CSSG is a Machiavellian group" or that its members or leaders have Machiavellian tendencies. That is, they are cunning, unscrupulous, opportunistic, and/or strategically brilliant (a bone for those who associate Machiavelli with positive qualities).

Given the use of "hacker" in the sentence, Computer Science Study Group seems a likely definition of the abbreviation. However, if the field of possibilities is wide open, other likely candidates might include:

**Combat Service Support Group (part of the U.S. Marines)

**The Canadian Summer School in Germany (likely highly Machiavellian)

**Compliance Surveillance Strategy Group (part of the Global Compliance Department of Goldman Sachs)

**Croma Security Solutions Group ("Protecting Assets in the Harshest Environments")

One interesting thing (in terms of English Language and Usage (this site's raison d'etre)) is that the quote uses **were** and **would have worked**. Perhaps this should lead us to the assumption that this Machiavelli is not, in fact, the infamous Niccolo Machiavelli of the 15th and 16th centuries, but rather an individual in our current midst who is not a hacker but who has some connection (similar ethics, for example) to the CSSG. Though I strongly suspect that it is just careless usage and the **were** should be **had been**.

Comment: I'd say that if Macchiavelli had been a hacker, he would have (would have had?) been out of work (excuse me if this is the incorrect tense, I'm not sure which one I should use in this case ;-) ), as there was little demand for hackers back in his day. On the other hand, if he was a hacker now, he'd have worked in CSSG (or elsewhere). Seriously though, I suppose the point is that the sentence is about what could be if he was alive today (and a hacker).

Comment: I don't see a problem with "were" in the original quote.  It is a past subjunctive form used for a timeless hypothetical, similar to "If wishes were horses, then beggars would ride."  As @tomasz says, "If Machiavelli had been a hacker" doesn't make sense in a historical sense, since the concept of computer hacker didn't exist in the 15th and 16th centuries.  So the sentence can be read as "If Machiavelli were alive today, and were he a hacker..."

Answer (score 2):

It means that whatever goes on at CSSG is *Machiavellian*. Machiavelli is most famous for his work *The Prince* which taught the benefits of unscrupulous and immoral behaviour in rulers. (The work itself is best seen as a satire, but that is ignored in modern uses of the word).

So maybe CSSG has a great deal of back-stabbing and skull-duggery going on?

Comment: When I was studying late-18th century history I discovered one writer who was quoting the 15th-century Machiavelli extensively. What I was unaware of, is that each age has viewed Machiavelli rather differently. But my man, one John Pitchford, writing in 1794, and an adherent of Rousseau, had taken the view that far from advocating 'a wicked and abominable king-craft', Machiavelli was actually promoting republicanism, through irony. I strongly recommend Femia's *Machiavelli Revisited* for a guide to the many faces, and interpretations of the Florentine philosopher across the ages.

Comment: @WS2: In my view, Machiavelli was disgusted by prevailing pieties about statecraft that undermined sensible governance. He didn't think that rulers could make good decisions unless they first understood what policies have worked in the past, and what policies have not. _The Prince_ was his analysis of what works most effectively in an autocracy. _Discourses on Livy_, which focused on republican Rome, was a comparable analysis of what works most effectively in a republic. It's a shame that he's associated solely with the ruthless tactics that he says (not without reason) work for an autocracy.

Comment: @SvenYargs I'm no expert but, as a would-be historian, it interested me that a philosopher could be interpreted divergently, in differing epochs. It fits with a notion that thought and ideas can be a product of historical circumstances, as well as the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to be sure with just one sentence to work on, but the writer is probably making an hypothetical assumption. The meaning is roughly: *I don't know if Machiavelli is a hacker. In the hypothetical present situation of his being a hacker, it is reasonable to assume that he worked for the CCSG (at some time in the past)*.

> **would: Presumption or expectation**

*•That would be Jo calling. I'll answer it.*

*We saw a police helicopter overhead yesterday morning.*
*Really? They would have been looking for those bank robbers.*
https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm